# XSLT error on xml transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I am getting an error on my xsl transform: 
Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added.

Here is my xsl. Any ideas? I researched and it might be i am inserting a subelement or copying and inserting subelement and then trying to add an attribute to the parent element but i cant see where i am doing this. Please help.

```
 <xsl:template match="legislation:lncontent" mode="lmt">
  <xsl:variable name="act">Act <xsl:value-of select="concat(//ln:actPrincipal/@number,' of   ',//ln:actPrincipal/@year)"/></xsl:variable>
  <!--note to check for ammendment also -->
  <lmt:xmlfile title="The Act">
    <lmt:mark name="{concat('XML_',$act)}" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
      <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </lmt:xmlfile>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"  name="identity">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
    <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="legislation:docBody">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
  <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="legislation:lncontent">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|node()">
  <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="legislation:section[@label]">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:param name="vAttribs" />
<xsl:variable name="title">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length(legislation:title)>0">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(./@label,'.   ',legislation:title)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(./@label,'.   ',legislation:body)"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<lmt:xmlfile title="{substring($title,1,string-length($title)-1)}">
  <lmt:mark>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mark">
        <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </lmt:mark>
  <lncontent>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//lncontent/namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//lncontent/@*"/>
    <docBody>
      <xsl:call-template name="identity" >
        <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </docBody>
  </lncontent>
</lmt:xmlfile>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="legislation:schedule[@label]">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:param name="vAttribs" />
<xsl:variable name="title">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="legislation:title/subTitle">
      <xsl:variable name="subtitle">
        <xsl:value-of select="legislation:title/subTitle"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="stitle">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(title,0,string-length($subtitle)-2)"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($stitle,' ',$subtitle)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!--!<xsl:value-of select="concat(title,' ',//db:body)"/>   -->
      <xsl:value-of select="legislation:title"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<lmt:xmlfile title="{$title}">
  <lmt:mark>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mark">
        <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </lmt:mark>
  <lncontent>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//lncontent/namespace::*"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//lncontent/@*"/>
    <docBody>
      <xsl:call-template name="identity" >
        <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </docBody>
  </lncontent>
 </lmt:xmlfile>
 </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="legislation:subSection[@label] | legislation:para[@label] |  legislation:subPara[@label] | legislation:item[@label]">
  <xsl:param name="act" />
  <xsl:if test="string-length(@label)>0">
  <lmt:mark>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mark">
        <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </lmt:mark>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:call-template name="identity" >
  <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="legislation:term">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<lmt:mark>
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="mark">
      <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:attribute>
</lmt:mark>
<xsl:call-template name="identity" >
  <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="legislation:term" mode="mark">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="term" mode="mark" />
<xsl:variable name="term">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('XML_',$act,' def: ',$term)" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="legislation:section" mode="mark">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:if test="ancestor::*[@label]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[@label][1]" mode="mark" >
    <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('XML_',$act,' s ',@label)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="legislation:schedule" mode="mark">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:if test="ancestor::*[@label]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[@label][1]" mode="mark"  />
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('XML_',$act,' sch ',@label)" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="legislation:*" mode="mark">
<xsl:param name="act" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[@label][1]" mode="mark" >
  <xsl:with-param name="act" select="$act"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:if test="string-length(@label) > '0'">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('(',@label, ')')" />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Template from where "legislation:lncontent" match is called

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:db="/schema/docBook"
    xmlns:ln ="/schema/LnNamespace"
    xmlns:lmt="/schema/lmt"
xmlns:lawreport=/schema/lawreport"
xmlns:legislation="/schema/legislation"
xmlns:programme="/schema/programme"
    xmlns:law24Publication = /schema/clientDevelopment/law24"
xmlns:law24Article = "/schema/clientDevelopment/law24/article"
    xmlns:pgsLandingPage = "/schema/PSL"
xmlns:pgsContent = "/schema/PGS">
    <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" method="xml" indent="yes" media-type="text/xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="db" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="ln" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="lawreport" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="legislation" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="programme" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="law24Article" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="law24Publication" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="pgsLandingPage" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="pgsContent" result-prefix="xml"/>
   <xsl:variable name="xslpath"></xsl:variable>



<xsl:template match="/">
<lmt:document>
  <xsl:variable name="xsl">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="legislation:*">BWAXlegislationpublication.xsl</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="lawreport:*">BWAXlawreportpublication.xsl</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="programme:*">BWAXprogrammepublication.xsl</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="law24Publication:*">BWAXlaw24Publication.xsl</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="law24Article:*">BWAXlaw24Article.xsl</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="pgsLandingPage:*">BWAXPGSPage.xsl</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="pgsContent:*">BWAXPGSContent.xsl</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="$xsl!=''">
    <xsl:attribute name="xsl">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($xslpath,$xsl)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:variable name="indexsheet">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="lawreport:*">XML.xil</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="$indexsheet!=''">
    <xsl:attribute name="indexsheet">
      <xsl:value-of select="$indexsheet"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="lmt"/>      
</lmt:document>
<!--<xsl:apply-templates mode="lmt"/>-->
</xsl:template>
```

Sample XML :

```
<lncontent xmlns="/schema/legislation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="/schema/legislation LNLegislation.xsd" xmlns:atieqn="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atieqn" xmlns:lng="/schema/Generic" xmlns:ln="/schema/LnNamespace" xmlns:md="/schema/metaData">
<docInfo filename="" lastupdated="" processdate="">
<lmt xmlns="/schema/metaData">
  <title title="" />
  <titlePath>
    <title1 groupid="" id=""></title1>
    <title2 groupid="" id=""></title2>
    <title3 groupid="" id=""></title3>
    <title4 groupid="" id=""></title4>
    <title5 groupid="" id=""></title5>
    <title6 groupid="" id=""></title6>
  </titlePath>
  <currentness>
    <currentness-author></currentness-author>
  </currentness>
</lmt>
<version creationDate="" lastVersionDate="" versionDate="" versionID="" xmlns="/schema/metaData" />
<search xmlns="/schema/metaData">
  <language language="En" />
  <referenceFrom fromDoc="from" toDoc="to" what="what" when="when" where="where" why="why" />
  <referenceTo fromDoc="from" toDoc="to" what="what" when="when" where="where" why="why" />
  <related docUrl="www.docurl.com" what="what" where="where" />
  <subject subject="act" />
  <documentType></documentType>
  <yearPublished>1996</yearPublished>
  <region></region>
  <publicationSource></publicationSource>
</search>
</docInfo>
</lncontent>
```

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples of XML input and XSLT code allowing us to reproduce the problem. Also tell us which XSLT processor you use. Does it not tell you where the problem occurs? I like testing with Saxon as it gives nice error messages.

Comment: Using VS 2010. On debugging it breaks on the copy statement of template name "identity"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#creating-attributes) of XSLT, the following is an error:

> Adding an attribute to an element after children have been added to
>   it; implementations may either signal the error or ignore the
>   attribute.

I can see two occurrences of where you are outputting a child element, but then trying to subsequently add an attribute to the parent. Both of these involve the following statements:

```
<lncontent>
  <xsl:copy-of select="//lncontent/namespace::*"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="//lncontent/@*"/>
```

This code occurs in the templates that match `legislation:section[@label]` and `legislation:schedule[@label]` respectively. If you swap the order of these two lines, then hopefully that should fix your problem.

Comment: Hmmm... I currently can't see any more occurences of the problem, other than the two places I mentioned. Could you consider posting a small sample of XML that would allow us to reproduce the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Engine name: Saxon6.5.5
Severity: error
Description: Cannot write a namespace declaration when there is no open start tag
Start location: 553:0

Comment: ..added sample xml to question.